# How do I programmatically upload pics and content on Google Content Delivery Network using jquery

Tags: jquery, google-app-engine

I want upload and download my web application contents and pics on GCDN .How can i perform this task using JQUery Api of Google Content Delivery Network .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have written full tutorial on this topic here,
http://verysimplescripts.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 2):

That's not how it works. Google doesn't really have a CDN to which you can upload file. It has a service that will allow you to have your web pages download their JS libraries from Google's servers. You can't add your files to it.

Also, Google has the Google Page Speed Service, which allows you to have Google be an intermediary for your web site and the user, but that involves changing your website's CNAME to point at Google's servers. Again, you don't directly upload the content; Google does it themselves.

Comment: Then what  process i should to use for up and down load images in my web application. My task is to upload products images by the user and display on products list .

Comment: You're going to need to store your images in a database and serve them from the database. Are you building your application on Google AppEngine?